# Assigning a Panel to each thread- Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, object

I have a program running several threads simultaneously. Each thread connects a database and transfers data from one table to another. Now I want to assign a panel to each thread in the MainForm  so I can change color of the Panel to green if the connection is successful or to red if it's broken after a number of retries.

So how can I tell a thread which Panel is its own Panel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a thread class, add a variable to store panel id:

```
type
TMyThread = class(TThread)
public
  PanelId: integer;
  constructor Create(APanelId: integer);
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(APanelId: integer);
begin
  inherited Create({CreateSuspended=}true);
  PanelId := APanelId;
  Suspended := false;
end;
```

For every thread create a panel and set it's Tag value to this Id:

```
for i := 1 to MaxThreads do begin
  threads[i] := TMyThread.Create(i);
  panels[i] := TPanel.Create(Self);
  panels[i].Tag := i;
end;
```

When your thread needs to update data on panel, it should send a specially defined message to the main form:

```
const
  WM_CONNECTED = WM_USER + 1;
  WM_DISCONNECTED = WM_USER + 2;
```

In wParam of this message you pass PanelId:

```
procedure TMyThread.Connected;
begin
  PostMessage(MainForm.Handle, WM_CONNECTED, PanelId, 0);
end;
```

In MainForm you catch this message, find the panel and update it:

```
TMainForm = class(TForm)
  {....}
protected
  procedure WmConnected(var msg: TMessage); message WM_CONNECTED;
end;

{...}

procedure TMainForm.WmConnected(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  panels[msg.wParam].Color := clGreen;
end;
```

Same with WmDisconnected.

The important thing here is that you CANNOT and NEVER should try to update visual components from threads other than the main thread. If you need to update user controls, you should post messages to the main form and create handler procedures, like in this example. These handler procedures will then be automatically called from the main thread.

Comment: As I remember, Synchronize() was designed by Borland exactly for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yeah, but Synchronize has its own flaws. It's roughly equal to SendMessage, and this approach will trigger deadlocks in any relatively complicated case. Avoid SendMessage, avoid Synchronize is a rule of thumb.

Comment: Elaborating on why SendMessage is a deadlock waiting to happen: the way to prevent deadlocks is order your locks. With SendMessage/Synchronize main thread queue becomes a kind of a lock too. You need it free to parse next message. For the main thread, this lock is obtained first (before anything else), because all the other locks are usually obtained while handling some message and blocking queue. For other threads, this lock is obtained last (when doing SendMessage). If you're in other locks at the time of SendMessage, you're potentially screwed.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir,
I know I am an idiot, I couldn't make created Panels visible.

Comment: After Creating the Panels

          panels[i]         := TPanel.Create(Self);
           panels[i].Tag     := i;
           panels[i].Height  := 25;
           panels[i].Width   := 64;
           panels[i].Top     := 48 + i*31;
           panels[i].Left    := 449;
           panels[i].Visible := True;

I tried to set ever property but on the Main form, I can not see any panels.

Comment: Try panels[i].Parent := Self; after panels[i] := TPanel.Create(Self);

Comment: @himself, another approach could be using TThread.Queue method which is roughly the same as sending a custom message to the main thread. TThread.Queue runs the code asynchronously so your thread won't be blocked when panel updating code is running in the context of the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

you really shouldn't be doing this - the UI should only be updated by the main thread.

Comment: Me, I'd have a main form array to associate thread and panel. And then a timer that reads the thread status and updates the appropriate panel. That way the thread gets on with its tasks, and the UI can be changed at any time without it needing to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign panel of main form thread because it is not thread-safe to update it. The thread can comunicate with application thread (main form) via windows messages or you must to use message queue. 
Check [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/index.htm) to simplify your work.