# How to prevent freezing MainForm and wait for return value from sub thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, tthread

I have thread where downloading xml file a this xml file i want to parse in other class. Now I have prepare thread, where I can download it.
In MainForm I'm using WaitForSingleObject, but this function freeze MainFrom, so how can I prevent reezing and wait for value?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't wait in the main thread. Arrange for the worker thread to send a message to the main thread to notify the main thread that work has been completed.

Comment: You should use windows messages for such purposes, see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377677/assigning-a-panel-to-each-thread-delphi

Comment: The TThread class has a Synchronize method (based upon Windows messages) for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, design your thread with events and invoke them using Synchronize.

Create thread in MainForm and assign event handlers to it:

```
Thread := TMyThread.Create(True);
Thread.OnDownload := DoDownload;
Thread.OnParse := DoParse;
// Other Events
Thread.Start;
```

You should not WaitFor* in MainForm. Avoid Windows messages method because your app will loose  platform portability, just linked to WinXX compilation.

Comment: At the end I do it by this way, bud now when I want to parse XML document by MSXML2_TLB I'm in deadlock.... Key word Synchronized I'm used... :/ Any advice? Deadlock start in line _xmldoc := t.DefaultInterface;_ in `t := TDomDocument40.Create(nil);
  xmldoc := t.DefaultInterface;`

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a good design to wait on the main thread, but in some cases it can be necessary. However, while you wait, you still need  to process messages coming to the thread.

Take a look at [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: I agree; my main goal is get value (xml in this case) back to MainForm. I don't care if I use one more thread for waiting... :) I think Boris Treukhlov's link can be helpfull...